SwiftUI : Pattern for navigating between views
I using following pattern to navigate between the views
@main
struct App: App {
    @ObservedObject var router = Router()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack() {
                HomeView()
                .navigationDestination(for: Router.Destination.self) { destination in
                    switch destination {
                    case .home:
                        HomeView()
                                   
                    case .livingroom:
                        LivingroomView()
                    case .bedroom(let owner):
                        BedroomView(ownerName: owner)
                    }
                }
                
            }
            .environmentObject(router)
        }
    }
}


class Router: ObservableObject {
    public enum Destination: Codable, Hashable {
        case home
        case livingroom
        case bedroom(owner: String)
    }
    
    @Published var navPath = NavigationPath()
    
    func navigate(to destination: Destination) {
        navPath.append(destination)
    }
    
    func navigateBack() {
        navPath.removeLast()
    }
    
    func navigateToRoot() {
        navPath.removeLast(navPath.count)
    }
}

It's ok on iOS >= 16 , But I don't know what should I do on iOS >= 15
Because NavigationStack and NavigationPath are only available on iOS 16 and above.

You should use NavigationView which is far more limited or UINavigationView which is far more complicated

NavigationView is replaced by NavigationStack, which is the way forward.

Unless you have a really specific reason iOS 15 and maybe even 16 isn’t worth the extra effort. Last I saw <10% of users were still on iOS 15 and below. That number will shrink even lower when iOS 18 is released.

https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/
